# How many equilaterals have vertices intersections of angle trisectors of a triangle?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, triangles

The celebrated ***Morley’s theorem*** ensures that *the interior trisectors, proximal to sides respectively, meet at vertices of an equilateral*.

In the paper [Trisectors like Bisectors with Equilaterals instead of Points](https://www.scielo.cl/pdf/cubo/v16n2/art05.pdf) it is shown that, among all triangles with vertices intersections of interior trisectors, only the Morley’ s theorem triangle is equilateral.

But *each angle has 6 trisectors*, as there are two more angles outside it. Thus, for the 6 trisectors of each angle of the triangle there are 18 Morley’s theorem valid variants, providing 18 equilaterals as [Alain Connes](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1998__S88__43_0.pdf) remarks. These equilaterals are depicted in the following figure with the Morley’ s theorem triangle in colour green.

[image]

Likely there no more equilaterals with vertices intersections of trisectors of all angles. Otherwise, Morley’s theorem wouldn’t be an extreme case leading to the formation of equilaterals.

[Richard Guy](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27642143)  has pointed out that 3 equilaterals have vertices the intersections of trisectors proximal to sides of two angles. In total 9 such equilaterals for the 3 pairs of angles in triangle. Conway suggested to be named *Guy Faux triangles*.  In the figure  27 equilaterals are seen, 18 Morley and 9 Guy Faux.

The paper [Holistic Approach of Morley’s general theorem](https://ijgeometry.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/9.-91-100.pdf) demostrates 9 equilaterals more with vertices intersections of angle trisectors of two angles (Fig.8a and 8b). For the 3 pairs of angles of the triangle, 27 such equilaterals (do not appear in the  figure).

18 equilaterals were considered surprisingly many. Even more so 54.

> *Are these all?*

Comment: This does not resemble a Ladas open problem. :-)